# Can I kill wifi on my Android, similar to how kill -9 would work on a desktop, to force restart it?

Tags: wi-fi, root-access, android-10, task-management

Since I upgraded to Android 10, wifi on my phone frequently "dies" and forces me to restart the phone. Is there a way to achieve something similar to what `kill -9` does on a desktop system on the processes responsible for wifi to force it to restart?

The problem is that wifi is turned of and can't be turned on again. If I tap the wifi switch in system preferences it briefly goes to `on` but then immediately reverts to `off`.

The device is rooted.

Comment: Kill `wpa_supplicant`. But that's not the solution to your problem.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Why not?

Comment: Go for fixing the actual problem, why WiFi toggles back to off. See logs, use `svc wifi` etc.

Comment: How do I "see logs", svc wifi etc?